# I do not get all of the data from the DB, trying to solve it by creating two Task functions, but now I recieve no Pin on the map

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work with a map and pins and when I load my data from my database I for some weird reason do not recieve all of the data and therefor not all of the pins, I load data from different cateogories/ID's and if I make two different functions loading the different ID I get the pins I did not get before but I cannot load them both at the same time and that is what I am asking for with this question.

How can I make it so the map adds the pins from my two functions? If I have the two functions on right now with my current code I get no pins, If i only load 1 function I get the data form that function and vice versa. I also connect the List of pins I created to a filter that I will also show.

This is the code:

```
    protected async override void OnAppearing() 
    {
        if (myPins.Count == 0) {

            myPins = await LoadData ();
            myPins = await LoadData2 (); //I do not get these pins on the map. If i however only load LoadData2 and remove LoadData. I get the pins on the map. But I want both of the functions to add the pins to the map.

            FilterPins (string.Empty); //i have a filter as well that I will show the code of below.  
        }

    }
```

And this is the function.

```
List<Pin> myPins = new List<Pin>();

private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
    {
        var pins = new List<Pin> ();

        var getItems = await phpApi.getPlacesInfo ();

            foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                theName = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
                theAdress = currentItem ["address"].ToString (); 
                theplacesCategory = currentItem ["ID"].ToString();


                if (theplacesCategory == "1") {

                            var pin = new Pin ();
                            pin.Position = new Position (p.Latitude, p.Longitude);
                            pin.Label = theName;
                            pin.Address = theId;

                            pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;

                            pins.Add (pin);
                } 
            }           
        }

        return pins;
    }
```

And the same code with my other function as above but different ID:

```
 private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData2()  //so this is the other function I load from.
    {
        var pins = new List<Pin> ();

        var getItems = await phpApi.getPlacesInfo ();

            foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                theName = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
                theAdress = currentItem ["address"].ToString (); 
                theplacesCategory = currentItem ["ID"].ToString();

                if (theplacesCategory == "2") { //Differnet id

                            //i add the same pins here as above.
                } 
            }           
        }

        return pins;
    }
```

I also have a filter that looks like this if that is the issue:

```
private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
    {
        map.Pins.Clear ();
        foreach(Pin p in myPins) {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter) || (p.Label.Contains(filter))) {
                map.Pins.Add (p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the second set of pins from `LoadData2()` you will want to do this:

```
myPins = await LoadData ();
myPins.AddRange(await LoadData2 ());
```

Otherwise you are just overwriting the first set.

Edit #4 (removed bad code I added previously): Change your filter function to this:

```
private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
{
    map.Pins.Clear ();

    foreach(Pin p in myPins) {
        if (p.Label.Contains(filter)) {
            map.Pins.Add (p);
        }
    }
}
```

So we are checking for `IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `IsNullOrWhitespace()` since you are passing in `string.Empty`.

Comment: This is so strange, If I use this code. The LoadData2 function runs, (like it reaches the function) but it doesnt put pins on the map as If I just use: `myPins = await LoadData2 ();`

Comment: And it finds the foreach function with that data inside, but doesnt add the pins that the data recieves on LoadData2 to the map

Comment: Also make sure all of your `Pin`s have a `Pin.Label` before being added to the map [see](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin/#Remarks)

Comment: @Yannick I changed the filter function a bit. If you pass in `string.Empty` there is no point to going through all of the pins so just assign the whole `List<Pin>`.

Comment: map.Pins = myPins; error: `property or indexer xamarin.forms.maps.pins cannot be assigned to (it is read only)`

Comment: @Yannick Guess I should have tried running it before suggesting you do it! Sorry about that.

Comment: Code runs. But still no sign of the pins from LoadData2.. hmm

Comment: Oh nvm, I actually did. Not all of the pins though. Maybe I need to create another LoadData 3 to separate the Id's even more (I have 7 ID's in total where I load different pins from) so more than I show in the code